# jQuery from one color to another

Tags: jquery, css, fade

I have this div field:

```
<div id="idNumber1" style="color: #ffcc00">hello</div>
```

So, we see yellow hello on the screen.

What I want to do:
I want the yellow hello to turn red and then fade out back to yellow. How can I do this?

Thank you for the answer.

Comment: when do you want it to change...on click? This is a pretty unclear question. voting to close.

Comment: AFAIK, jQuery does not support the animation of colors without a plugin.

Comment: @Sparky672 when you do animations using `animate()` i think it changes (fades and transforms) colors similar to CSS transitions. doesn't it?

Comment: @iight, [No, it does not.  See `.animate()`.](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Comment: @Sparky672 you are correct! (just tried it) I thought I've done it but evidently not. CSS 1 - Jquery 0..(not really)

Comment: It is supposed to change when one javascript function is called. I have everything done, but I need to find the way to fade from one color to another

Comment: For a question about javascript, it is really lacking some javascript code. :)

Comment: Come on. It's not lacking anything. I need to find out how to fade colors, so there will be something like $("#idNumber1"). and here something that will do the job. Whoever knows how to do it, won't even need anything I wrote, it's just to make easier to understand what I'm looking for ;)

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, the `animate()` function by itself will not alter colors. However, it can be combined with CSS3 transitions to achieve the desired effect:

```css
#idNumber1 {
  color: #ffcc00;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.5s linear;
}
```

```js
function flash(id) {
  $(id).css('color', '#ff0000');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(id).css('color', '#ffcc00');
  }, 500);
}
```

Call it like so, this will change the color to red over 500ms and then change it back to yellow over 500ms:

```
flash('#idNumber1');
```

Of course, `idNumber1` isn't the most descriptive and you might want to consider something better, or using a class name to signify elements with this behaviour. You'll also likely want to include all or some of the full browser prefix transitions:

```css
-webkit-transition: color 1s linear;
-moz-transition: color 1s linear;
-o-transition: color 1s linear;
-ms-transition: color 1s linear;
transition: color 1s linear;
```

There are lots of other ways of doing this, here is just one.